# RestTemplate - missing every number beyond milliseconds

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, resttemplate

In the rest web service (e.g. @Controller) I can see the time with more than milliseconds but in the client consuming the rest web service through RestTemplate every characters beyond the third digital is missed. For instance, I can see 2014-12-22 09:52:35.371444 and 2014-12-22 09:52:34.00934 when I look at the return from the rest web service (return testReturn) but I will see 1419263555371 and 1419263554009 when I look at the client side ( _l ). I am not asking about the format (2014-12-22 09:52:35.371444 versus 1419263555371). I am asking about losing 444 in the first example and 34 in the second example. Please, if someone point some solution with "objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.etc)" show me how to set this to affect RestTemplate. I need the return to "LogDisplay _l = restTemplate.postForObject" be filled in with the complete timestamp from "return testReturn".

//client side

```
LogDisplay _l = restTemplate.postForObject(myServiceUrl,myPojoParameters, LogDisplay.class);
```

//the pojo related to the question

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Lo_DisplayRecord { 
 String isParsable;
 private Timestamp dateTime;
       public Lo_DisplayRecord(String parseSw, Timestamp timeStamp){
              super();
              isParsable    = parseSw;
              dateTime      = timeStamp; //the question is related to this variable
       }
```

//Pojo containing other pojo

```
@Component
public class LogDisplay {
       public LogDisplay(){}
       private ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord> displayValues; //pojo with the datetime variable
       private int reportRowsLimit = 0;
       private int reportRowsCount = 0;
       public int getReportRowsLimit() {
              return reportRowsLimit;
       }
       public ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord> getDisplayValues() {
              return displayValues;
       }
       public void setDisplayValues(ArrayList displayValues) {
              this.displayValues = displayValues;
       }
}
```

//rest web service

```
   @Autowired
   private LogDisplay testReturn;

   @RequestMapping(value="display/last", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
   public LogDisplay getLast(@RequestBody Mas60010 mas60010) {

          try {
                 testReturn = lo_Mas60010.getLastDisplayValues(
              return testReturn;
```

[image: RestTemplate.postForObject executed before ObjectMapper.Configure takes effect]

//mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

From jackson documentation:

> WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS (default: false) (since Jackson 2.2)
>   Feature that controls whether numeric timestamp values are expected to be written using nanosecond timestamps (enabled) or not (disabled); if disabled, standard millisecond timestamps are assumed.

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS,true);
```

This should work.

edit:

> READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS (default: false) -- Since Jackson 2.2
>   Feature that controls whether numeric timestamp values are expected to be written using nanosecond timestamps (enabled) or not (disabled); if disabled, standard millisecond timestamps are assumed.

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS,true);
```

There is also configuration for deserialization.

Comment: no, it will not work. After I call the rest web service by "restTemplate.postForObject(myServiceUrl,myPojoParameters, LogDisplay.class)" I lost the nanosecond timestamps. I need someway to enable the feature "WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS" in RestTemplate. As I said in my question, " if someone point some solution with "objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.etc)" show me how to set this to affect RestTemplate".

Comment: I added a picture where I show you that your suggestion will not work in my case. Please, look at line 131 where I call the rest web service. If I show you the result inside _l you will see that the nanoseconds are lost. How can I make ObjectMapper.configure interferes in RestTemplate.postForObject? Is there a way to set "DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS,true" in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, maybe under MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter?

Comment: It seems that I can make changes to the messageConverter (restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters)) but I didn't figure out how to change it yet.